# Error loading shared libraries: libstdc++.so.6

Tags: 18.04, shared-library

When I use

```
$apt-get update
```

Output- `error while loading shared libraries:libstdc++.so.6`

```
$apt-file search libstdc++.so.6
File usr/lib/command not found
```

How can I add this library?

---

```
$ lsb_release -a 
No LSB modules are available. 
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS 
Release: 18.04 
Codename: bionic

$ apt-cache policy libapt-pkg?.0
apt-cache: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)
```

Comment: The main thing which I can't understand - why APT tries to locate `libapt-pkg.so.6.0` from newer version of Ubuntu (20.04 LTS) rather than standart libapt-pkg.so.5.0. Did you tried to upgrade this system? Did this upgrade failed?

Comment: yes the system was upgraded and it was failed

Comment: It is a bit bad, that you did not mention it at start. See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install [corresponding packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=amd64&searchon=contents&keywords=gnu%2Flibstdc%2B%2B.so.6) manually by

```
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_i386.deb

wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-10/libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i libstdc++6_10-20200411-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and then you will be able to run

```
sudo apt update
```

and

```
sudo apt install --reinstall libstdc++6 libstdc++6:i386 libapt-pkg6.0
sudo apt install command-not-found apt-file
```

Comment: Sudo apt is not working

Comment: Sudo dpkg above gives error " package libstdc++6:amd64 8.4.0~18.04 cannot be configured because libstdc++6:i386 is at different version

Comment: See updated answer. Install 32-bit first, then 64-bit.

Comment: now after sudo apt update "apt: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libapt-pkg.so.6.0)" this error is showing

Comment: Maybe you can adjust your answer, how to find the matching version of the package that is missing. Simply copying those commands with those links will not help many people